# Bioinformatics journal split long url

Tags: line-breaking, templates, split, url

I am using the Latex template of the journal Bioinformatics, it can be accessed here: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/submission_online

It is a 2 columns template. I have a long url I am trying to display but it's not broken properly and extend through the page, basically the line is too long.

```
\href{https://github.com/jnarayan81/Alienomics/blob/master/install-dependencies_AO.sh}{https://github.com/jnarayan81/Alienomics/blob/master/install-dependencies_AO.sh}
```

Here is the result: 
[image: github url not warped]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try loading `xurl`.

Comment: sorry a backslash escape is necessary in my example for the code to compile
`\href{https://github.com/jnarayan81/Alienomics/blob/master/install-dependencies_AO.sh}{https://github.com/jnarayan81/Alienomics/blob/master/install-dependencies\_AO.sh}`

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Use `\url` instead `\href` and load package `xurl`. That should do what you want. If you want more help show us a short compiling tex code resulting in your issue!

Comment: @Mensh of course, it indeed works perfectly with `\url` Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments ...